# DataGridView not showing all rows

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2012, datagridview

I have a DataGridView form (System.Windows.Forms) in VS2012 (VB) that looks fine when I Preview it in VS: [image: code preview]

Yet when I recompile and run the program, the latest line I added to the Access file is missing (ID 19, which I added as 20 then pushed it to 19; ID 20 is always hidden). The data source is an Access file with 1 simple table.

Here's what it looks like in the recompiled program:

[image: executed program]

As you can see, there is still 1 row missing. And row 20 is still correctly hidden, which is right. But I'm not sure why the new row (19) is still missing.

I believe the `Fill()` and `GetData()` function are all standard. Any thoughts?

The rest of the form works fine; it pulls numbers from the Access file and updates (Refresh) them on the program display.

Comment: What platform, Windows Forms?

Comment: So, is this a problem that the DGV is not refreshing to show the recently added row? I believe `.Refresh()` handles that.

Comment: @WillMarcouiller Yes "System.Windows.Forms"

Comment: Are you using a `BindingSource` to bind everything together?

Comment: @WillMarcouiller Yes. And everything updates and refreshes just fine (numbers in columns, etc) so it's refreshing fine. It just hasn't added the new row yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took a while to find, but I dug out this line in a refresh function:

```
xxxxxx.Filter = "ID < 19"
```

And change it to 20.

Comment: No one but you could have found this! =)